# How to connect PHPMyadmin DB by creating the batch file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have created the sql file to create table in DB.

I am using PHPMYAdmin But i am not able to connect to the DB.

I want to run this as Batch file.

If i try to MYSQL from command prompt it give error as

```
 'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

Regards,
Dev

Comment: Where do you have mySQL installed?

Comment: I have installed phpmyadmin though Xampp installer......which has package of apache and MySql

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is an interactive web application; it's not designed to be batch executed. If you want something scriptable or that you can run as a batch file, you should be using the command-line client or even the library functions of your scripting language (Python, PHP, Ruby, etc).

That error message indicates that the MYSQL program is not in your path. Generally XAMPP installs a menu item for the command-line client; try looking in your program menu for a shortcut for it. You'll probably also easily find the executable on disk in the XAMPP folder, then just need to specify the path or add that directory to your path statement.